# How i can send recently save data into template in same view function in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, class, model

**view.py**
In the below code, I'm saved my recent data in model and create a dictionary `order = order.save()` because I can use this in my template. When I run the code the order is having ```None`` value.

What i can do for it.

```
     def post(self, request, product_id):
          product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
          if request.POST['address'] and request.POST['quantity']:
               order = Order()
               order.or_proName = product.pro_name
               order.or_companyName = product.companyName
               order.or_quatity = request.POST['quantity']
               order.or_quatity = int( order.or_quatity)
               orderPrice = order.or_quatity*product.Sale_Price
               order.or_bill = 100 + orderPrice
               order.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
               product.Quantity -= order.or_quatity
               product.save()
               order = order.save()
               args = {'order':order}
               return render(request, self.red_templateName, args)
```

Comment: You should not use `order = order.save()`, but just `order.save()`

Comment: order.save() is a function within your model. It does not return anything usually so your variable "order" will be empty. You can just call order.save() without assigning it to a variable just as you did with the product. After that you can pass the order to your template as usually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `django.db.models.Model.save()` does not usually return anything (unlike the `django.forms.Form.save()` function)

Remove the line `order = order.save()` from your code

You can see how the `Model.save()` is implemented here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L666

Answer (score 2):

You should not assign the result of the `.save()` function to `order`, since that is indeed `None`. Just `.save()` the order, and use the `order` function further in your view:

```
def post(self, request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    if request.POST['address'] and request.POST['quantity']:
        order = Order()
        order.or_proName = product.pro_name
        order.or_companyName = product.companyName
        order.or_quatity = request.POST['quantity']
        order.or_quatity = int( order.or_quatity)
        orderPrice = order.or_quatity*product.Sale_Price
        order.or_bill = 100 + orderPrice
        order.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
        product.Quantity -= order.or_quatity
        product.save()
        order.save()
        args = {'order':order}
        return render(request, self.red_templateName, args)
```

You should however define an `else` case as well, since the `post` method is supposed to *always* return a `HttpResponse` object, for example an error mesage.